# Couldn't find the project type when creating a project in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I think this is probably a basic question, but I just could not find the button. I was trying to create a new Android project from the starting page. But when I click on New Project it gives me a page with the options of Java, Maven, Gradle, Groovy Griffin... instead of the familiar starting page with Blank App, Google Map, etc. [image]

When I opened a previous project, it opens Tags like C:, Users, Android, etc. The image is below: [image]

Any idea how do I find that page back?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know what happened, but I closed Android Studio for one day. When I opened it the second day, it got back normal. (I also closed all project when closing the Studio.)

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update the SDK first, by SDK Manager.

Comment: It's not a version issue. I just installed it this past week. Also, I was able to do it last Saturday. Not sure if I accidentally changed some setting or path to take it there. As I mentioned, now when I open a project the interface looks different too.